# C# Core, OracleDataReader with hasRows as false while select all rows in a table that has data

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core, oracle-manageddataaccess

I am testing Oracle database. I wrote some code but my datareader has no rows, why? My "carros" table has data and I am selecting all of them but I am getting an empty result set it seems.

```
            string constr = "Data Source=localhost:1521/XE;User Id=System;Password=password;";
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);


            OracleCommand oracleCommand = new OracleCommand();

            oracleCommand.Connection = con;
            oracleCommand.CommandText = "select preco from carro";
            con.Open();
            OracleDataReader oracleDataReader = oracleCommand.ExecuteReader();


            string resultado = String.Empty;

            //My test, I got hasRows as false
            if (oracleDataReader.HasRows == false)
            {
                resultado = "no results";
            }        

           //never enters this loop.
            while (oracleDataReader.Read())
            {
                resultado += (string)oracleDataReader["preco"];

            }


            // Close and Dispose OracleConnection
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();

            return resultado;
```

Answer (score 0):

If HasRows is false after ExecuteReader, the problem is simply that the query is returning no rows so Read will return false as well.  Perhaps the someValue variable is not set correctly.

From you description, it seems that your table is named `carros` while your query has used `carro`. Try to use

```
oracleCommand.CommandText = "select preco from carros";
```

Comment: No, it's carro, I use singular table names.

Answer (score 0):

A path towards solving this can include a scattering of logging commands that write to the file system.

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"\\server\\C\\log.txt", "put error message here" + "\r\n");
```

Or for printing a variable:

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"\\server\\C\\log.txt", ex.ToString() + "\r\n");
```

Pepper variations of this command throughout your script to see where failures are happening and to validate variable values.